Use all array values as dimension filter
I am trying to use a time slot filter for a chart in SAC. The filter should include all months from January till the current month. This is the code I am using, but unfortunately it only shows the last month. The filter should be set when the page opens.
function onInitialization() : void
    var currentDate = new Date(Date.now());
    var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
    var timeSlot = ArrayUtils.create(Type.string);
 
    chartCompare.getDataSource().removeDimensionFilter("0CALMONTH2");
 
    for (var i = 1; i<=currentMonth; i++)
    {
        timeSlot[i]="0"+i.toString();
        chartCompare.getDataSource().setDimensionFilter("0CALMONTH2", timeSlot[i]); 
    }

The chart is filtered by month but the previous months are removed.
